# Implementing streaming video for Windows 10 UAP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I need to display in XAML a video stream coming from some network source. Video frames can come at undefined intervals. They're already assembled, decoded and presented in BGRA8 form in memory mapped file. XAML frontend is in C#, backend is written in C using WinAPI.

In C# I have a handle of this file.

Previously in .NET 4.5 I was creating InteropBitmap from this handle with `System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromMemorySection` and called `Invalidate` on arriving of new frame. Than I used this `InteropBitmap` as `Source` for XAML `Image`.

Now I need to do the same but for Windows 10 UAP platform.
There are no memory mapped files in .NET Core so I created a CX Windows Runtime Component. Here's most important part of it.

```
static byte* GetPointerToPixelData(IBuffer^ pixelBuffer, unsigned int *length)
{
    if (length != nullptr)
    {
        *length = pixelBuffer->Length;
    }
    // Query the IBufferByteAccess interface.
    ComPtr<IBufferByteAccess> bufferByteAccess;
    reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(pixelBuffer)->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&bufferByteAccess));

    // Retrieve the buffer data.
    byte* pixels = nullptr;
    bufferByteAccess->Buffer(&pixels);
    return pixels;
}

void Adapter::Invalidate()
{
    memcpy(m_bitmap_ptr, m_image, m_sz);
    m_bitmap->Invalidate();
}

Adapter::Adapter(int handle, int width, int height)
{
    m_sz = width * height * 32 / 8;
    // Read access to mapped file
    m_image = MapViewOfFile((HANDLE)handle, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, m_sz);

    m_bitmap = ref new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
    m_bitmap_ptr = GetPointerToPixelData(m_bitmap->PixelBuffer, 0);
}

Adapter::~Adapter()
{
    if ( m_image != NULL )
        UnmapViewOfFile(m_image);
}
```

Now I can use m_bitmap as Source for XAML Image ( and don't forget to raise property change on invalidate otherwise image won't update ).

Is there a better or more standard way? How can I create `WriteableBitmap` from `m_image` so I won't need additional memcpy on invalidate?

UPDATE: I wonder if I can use MediaElement to display sequence of uncompressed bitmaps and get any benefits from it? MediaElement supports filters which is a very nice feature.

Comment: Usually, I will use bitmap->SetSourceAsync(stream) to set the source of the bitmap, do you have any concerns of using it in your scenario?

Comment: if i call SetSourceAsync there's no need to call Invalidate() and raise property change on every frame? I'm not sure writing to additional "Stream" object will not create additional bitmap copy.

This app runs on the phone. The basic idea is to make it as fast as possible and use as low memory as possible because uncompressed bitmap is rather large. I think there's nothing faster than native memcpy() to native WriteableBitmap buffer. Actually now it's already fine, smooth and fast. I just wonder if there's a better way.